# How to Create Dynamic Routes in Next.js

Tags: next.js, url-routing

How Add flexibility to my routing with a quick spot of URL inspection?

I want an address for the product details page, part of which is static and part of which is dynamic:

[www.shop.com/product-{productid}-{productname}](http://www.shop.com/product-%7Bproductid%7D-%7Bproductname%7D)

like the :

[www.shop.com/product-1-applewatch](http://www.shop.com/product-1-applewatch)

[www.shop.com/product-9-maclaptap](http://www.shop.com/product-9-maclaptap)

Is this possible in next.js?

Thank you for reading the question.

I found this too but it didn't solve my problem:
https://www.makeuseof.com/nextjs-dynamic-routes-create/

Comment: no i need url like [product-id-productname]       replace "/" with "-"

Comment: this is doable but I don't know if it's a good way to do dynamic routes. first are you using Next.js 13 or 12.x.x?

Comment: i'm using 12.x.x          i want  my url  be like [product-id-productname] replace "/" with "-"

Comment: are you planning to use `getStaticProps` with `getStaticPaths` or `getServerSideProps` ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow your requirement, you can generate some url be like these:

- `www.shop.com/product/1/applewatch`
- `www.shop.com/product/1?productName=applewatch` 
  **or**  `www.shop.com/product?productId=1&productName=applewatch`

---

**Reference**: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Comment: i want  my url like ==>product-1-applewatch

not this  ==>product/1/applewatch


without querystring